# Lookup Pixelshader with HLSL & XNA

Tags: xna, hlsl

First of all I'm new to XNA and HLSL so me knowledge is very limited.

I'm writing a small Application to display a digital elevation model consisting of 16Bit values in 2D by using different colors for different height.
The colormapping is done by a Pixelshader via a lookup texture.
At the moment I'm putting the values into red an green components of a texture2D and map them to colors in a 256x256 texture.
As the coloring is discrete/not continously I set minfilter/magfilter to point what leads to a blocky look when zooming in.
Is there a way to get the linear filtering back after the lookup? Or does anybody know a better way to do the mapping?

Shader:

```
sampler2D tex1 : register(s0) = sampler_state
{
MinFilter = Point;
MagFilter = Point;
MipFilter = linear; 
}; 

texture2D lookupTex;
sampler2D lookup = sampler_state
{
Texture = <lookupTex>; 

MinFilter = Point;
MagFilter = Point;
MipFilter = Point; 
};

float4 PixelShaderLookup(float4 incol : COLOR, float2 UV : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
float4 inCol = tex2D(tex1, UV);

half3 scale = (256 - 1.0) / 256;
half3 offset = 1.0 / (2.0 * 256);

float4 outCol = tex2D(lookup, scale * inCol.gr + offset);

return outCol;
}
```

Thanks for your help and a happy new year :)